# While I am going send request to review my API transaction. Review did not pass.Compliance with [[linkstart]]API rules and limits[[linkEnd]]

Tags: docusignapi

I am using sandbox account for docusign everything is working fine. Now I want do this for LIVE account for this I have followed this URL https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live-steps#review-failed.
While I am going send request to review my AIP transaction. I am getting response Review did not pass.Error in 3rd step. Compliance with [[linkstart]]API rules and limits[[linkEnd]].
Here is a snap shot of error page
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O7zCfDGHf5YIbZ0EtnWmr7N3hKjvmApG
I have downloaded a error logs. No error found in this log
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jXxkf53g9_ELsRnEjF44qrMkDpIuV-dt

Answer (score 0):

This review failed due to a known issue in the automated review process (tracked under DCM-3308). In short, the GetEnvelopes call isn't properly tracked, so the review cannot correctly distinguish between valid traffic that complies with the Polling rule and invalid traffic that does not.

For anyone else who encounters this issue (Specifically, with the GetEnvelopes call appearing in the traffic CSV): First confirm your traffic is not polling for the same resource more than once every fifteen minutes, then reach out to go-live@docusign.com: provide your integration key and the CSV of review traffic.